# Django signal simple snippet confusion?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is a simple Django signal snippet I found on the internet to generate a profile after User creation. What is the need of the second post_save signal. Didn't the first 'create' already save the profile? So why was the second receiver created?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: The second signal saves the current changes in the `Profile` instance, whenever a `User` instance is updated/saved.

Comment: first it is like `auto_now_add=True` for instance and second it is like `auto_now=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `created` argument of `post_save` signal denotes if the instance is saved before (ie. it is newly created or not). The first handler *creates* a new `Profile` instance for the newly created `User`, while the second saves the already instantiated `Profile` instance whenever the `User` is saved.

That being said, the two handlers could have been merged into one:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```